# Create JVM crashs outside from Visual Studio

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2013, jvm, java-native-interface

i have following Problem. I write a little Application , that creates a Java Virtual Machine. If I start this programm inside of Visual Studio it works fine. But if i start it outside of visual studio the programm does not work and i have a ntdll.dll crash.

Here is my Code :

```
    int result = 0;

LoadRuntimeLibrary(libPath);



// Load the JVM library 
g_jniLibrary = LoadLibrary(libPath);

if (g_jniLibrary == NULL) {

    info->Error("Could not load libary: ");
    return -1;
}

// Grab the create VM function address
JNI_createJavaVM createJavaVM = (JNI_createJavaVM)GetProcAddress(g_jniLibrary, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
if (createJavaVM == NULL) {
    info->Error("ERROR: Could not find JNI_CreateJavaVM function");
    return -1;
}

// Count the vm args
int numVMArgs = -1;
while (vmArgs[++numVMArgs] != NULL) {}

// Add the options for exit and abort hooks
int numHooks = 0;

JavaVMOption* options = (JavaVMOption*)malloc((numVMArgs + numHooks) * sizeof(JavaVMOption));

for (int i = 0; i < numVMArgs; i++){
    options[i].optionString = vmArgs[i];
    options[i].extraInfo = 0;
}


// Setup hook pointers

options[numVMArgs].optionString = "abort";
options[numVMArgs].extraInfo = (void*)&AbortHook;
options[numVMArgs + 1].optionString = "exit";
options[numVMArgs + 1].extraInfo = (void*)&ExitHook;

JavaVMInitArgs init_args;
memset(&init_args, 0, sizeof(init_args));

init_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
init_args.options = options;
init_args.nOptions = numVMArgs + numHooks;
init_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;



result = createJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &init_args); // here is the crash





 env = GetJNIEnv(false);


Init(env);



result = RunMainClass(env, mainCls, argc, javaargs);

jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
FreeLibrary(g_jniLibrary);

return result;
```

I hope you hava any idea , what could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `options` array out of bounds. It only contains `numVMArgs` elements, as `numHooks` is zero.

This of course leads to *undefined behavior* when you do

```
options[numVMArgs].optionString = "abort";
options[numVMArgs].extraInfo = (void*)&AbortHook;
options[numVMArgs + 1].optionString = "exit";
options[numVMArgs + 1].extraInfo = (void*)&ExitHook;
```

as the indexes `numVMArgs` and `numVMArgs + 1` are out of bounds.

Comment: but where is the mistake here : JavaVMOption* options = (JavaVMOption*)malloc((numVMArgs + numHooks) * sizeof(JavaVMOption)); i allocate to little memory.